# How to Render this Array in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

Hi I want to render this Advice on the screen but I could not do it I tried to map but that didn't helped please help me

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function UsersData() {
  const [Users, setUsers] = useState([{
    "slip": {
      "id": 41,
      "advice": "Don't use Excel or Powerpoint documents for your basic word processing needs."
    }
  }])

  return(
    <>
      <h2> React Fetch API Example </h2>
        <ul>
          {/* Not sure what to write here */}
        </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I tried `{Users.map(e=>{e.slip})` but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you try in terms of your mapping logic?

Comment: I tried {Users.map(e=>{e.slip}) but that didn't worked

Comment: Yeah that won't work because it would try to render `slip` or each `user`. But slip is an object. Try my answer. And if that works for you please consider marking the answer as a solution( ✅ ) to close the loop. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as writing a mapping function:

```
export default function UsersData() {
  const [Users, setUsers] = useState([
    {
      slip: {
        id: 41,
        advice:
          "Don't use Excel or Powerpoint documents for your basic word processing needs.",
      },
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>React Fetch API Example</h2>
      <ul>
        {Users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.slip.id}>{user.slip.advice}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywxgpv) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

Using map function you can print whole array and sample code below here.

```
<ul>
    {Users.map((element) => (
      <li key={element.slip.id}>{element.slip.advice}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function UsersData() {
  const [Users, setUsers] = useState([
    {

      "slip": {
      "id": 41,
      "advice": "Don't use Excel or Powerpoint documents for your basic word processing needs."
      }
      }
  ])



  return (
    <>
      <h2>React Fetch API Example</h2>
      <ul>
        {Users.map(({slip})=>(
           <li key={slip.id}>{slip.advice}</li>
        ))}
      
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>React Fetch API Example</h2>
    <ul>
      {Users.map((user) =>
        Object.keys(user).map((key) => (
          <li>
            {user[key].id} - {user[key].advice}
          </li>
        ))
      )}
    </ul>
```